# How many solutions are there to the equation (Is the solution wrong?)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is, How many solutions are there to the equation : $x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 72$ when $x_i \ge 0, i = 1, . . . , 5$

The solution was:
$$x_1 +x_2 +x_4 +x_5 =72−2x_3 $$
$$\iff x_1 +x_2 +x_4 +x_5 =2x_3$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{36} \dbinom{2_i+3}{3}$$

I'm not really sure where the 72 disappeared and why i=0 and not i=1 possibly?

Comment: Because $0 \le x_3 \le 36$. But what is $2_i$ in the upper index?

Comment: Oops made a typo, edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_1+x_2+x_4+x_5=72-2x_3=2(36-x_3)$ so I re-define $x_3\equiv36-x_3$ hence $0\le x_3\le36$. The solution (for all possible values of $x_3$):

$$\sum_{x_3=0}^{36}\binom{2x_3+3}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Matt! The only part I don't understand is how you got the inequality $0 \le x_3 \le 36$?

Comment: That is because if $x_3>36$  we'll get a negative number on the RHS...in other words $36-x_3$ must be positive or null.

Comment: That answered my question Thanks again!